# Deedy-Resume: how remove hanging indent in list

Tags: indentation, bullets, deedy-resume

I'm trying to make things as compact as possible on the Deedy-Resume template, and I've reduced the space between the lines, and I've made multiple adjustments to save space. 
I'd like to remove the hanging indent, or at least control the spacing, on the indent on the lines after the initial bullet line.
I'm using overleaf, and the compiler is XeLatex

Full file can be found here http://ge.tt/5KplYRx2

[image: trying to be able to control the indent spacing]

Below is the section that deals with the bullet points. Also i'm using the enumitem package.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage[hmargin= 1.0cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry} % Specifies horizontal and vertical page margins

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE STYLING AND SPACING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{tightitemize} % Defines the tightitemize environment which modifies the itemize environment to be more compact
{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize} \leftmargin-25pt \itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt \itemindent-20pt \labelsep1pt \parindent0pt
}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}




\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.72\textwidth} 


\subsection*{Research Assistant} 
\subsubsection*{Apr 2014 - Aug 2014 | TEST, NY}
\begin{tightitemize}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item\lipsum[4]
\end{tightitemize}

\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add a compilable MWE, without that it is very hard to help you. Nevertheless, welcome to TEXSE.

Comment: I uploaded the complete sample file. I hope that helps? wasn't sure how to slim down the .cls file

Comment: Please do not add external links, they will die over time. Please encapsulate your scripts within this question itself.

Comment: I hope the updated code is more informative.

Comment: Yep you got ky vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use environment `itemize` with some options, because you called already `enumitem` like this:

```
\begin{itemize}[% <=====================================================
  noitemsep,nosep,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelsep=2pt,
  itemindent=0pt,
  labelwidth=*
]
```

An better result you would get with the following lines, but then you get an odd warning about negative labelwidth "making no sense".

```
\begin{itemize}[% <=====================================================
  noitemsep,nosep,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelsep=2pt,
  itemindent=0pt,
  labelwidth=-7pt
]
```

IMHO It makes sense to use a negative length because the odd definition of `\labelwidth`:

[image: screenshot of docu]

As you can see in the screenshot above the `\labelwdth` is defined to reach into `\leftmargin`, but what happend if that length is set t o zero?

In the following MWE I added an `\fbox` to visualize the printed `minipage` with an frame around it.

Please see the following MWE (code changings marked with `<======`)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage[%
  hmargin= 1.0cm, vmargin=0.75cm,
% showframe
]{geometry} % Specifies horizontal and vertical page margins

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION TITLE STYLING AND SPACING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{tightitemize} % Defines the tightitemize environment which modifies the itemize environment to be more compact
{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] \itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt \itemindent0pt \labelsep1pt \parindent0pt
}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}


\begin{document}

\fbox{% <===============================================================
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.72\textwidth} 
\subsection*{Research Assistant} 
\subsubsection*{Apr 2014 - Aug 2014 | TEST, NY}
\begin{tightitemize}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item\lipsum[4]
\end{tightitemize}
New itemize follows now:
\begin{itemize}[% <=====================================================
  noitemsep,nosep,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  labelsep=2pt,
  itemindent=0pt,
  labelwidth=*
]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
} % <===================================================================

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Your solution is printed first (see red arrow marked 1), my solution is printed second. See that I'm closer to the left start of the frame (red arrow 2) and the text bullet is going a little bit outside the frame on the left. If you do not want this use my second solution with negative `\labelwith` and resulting warning:

[image: second possibility I showed]

At last I see this is a bug in that package, it should be possible to start the text bullet inside the frame without warning. Perhaps you want to contact the maintainer of that package?

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed, and thorough response. I do like your example better, but are you saying that my modification doesn't work as well because it is a bug with the package `enumitem`

Comment: @habitual_programmer No, your example works but left a little bit bigger white space on the left than my examples. The bug I mentioned is that the label is as standard printed outside the added red line in the screenshot of the documenttion. That is the reason that the text bullet is printed before the left line of the frame (see red arrow 3). To avoid this one have to use negative labelwidth with resulting warning (that is the bug INHO; see red arrow in last screenshot of second possibility).

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `\newcommand` to the following fixed the issue:
Pay attention to the `leftmargin`

```
\newenvironment{tightitemize} % Defines the tightitemize environment which modifies the itemize environment to be more compact
{\vspace{-\topsep}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] \itemsep0pt \parskip0pt \parsep0pt \itemindent0pt \labelsep1pt \parindent0pt
}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-\topsep}}
```